# How to get the name of block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

E.g, we have

```
typedef id(^func)(id);
func read_file = ^(NSString *path_to_file) {
     return [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path_to_file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
};
```

I wonder how can we get the name of this block if I passed it as a parameter in some function call?
E.g,

```
fileOperator(read_file); // I want to print the block's name in this function.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Blocks don't have names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I wonder how can we get the name of this block if I passed it as a parameter in some function call?

You can't get the name of a block passed as a parameter any more than you can get the name of an `int` variable passed as a parameter. The name isn't part of the block... the name is associated with a variable that contains the block.

Assuming you've passed the block as a parameter, you should use the parameter name to refer to the block just as you'd use the name of an `int` parameter to refer to the integer value passed into a function or method.